# Newly added strings in resx can't be resolved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, resx

I have a UWP application with Resource Files (.resx) for translation in a .net standard 2.0 library. When I add new strings there and try to resolve them I get "null" in return. All the existing strings are available and resolved correctly. Here is an example:

[image]

When I follow the reference, I see that there is actually an entry in the designer: [image]

Also I can see it in the xml of the resource file:

[image]

What can be wrong here?

EDIT: Here is the Link to the project: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

EDIT2: I found out that the issue is with files for different languages. If I add the new string in all my language files the string is resolved properly. So it seems that the fallback does not work as it should.

Comment: I just created a new UWP project and added a new .NET Standard 2.0 project with a RESX and it is working fine -- can you share more details? What does your project look like?

Comment: I added the link to the repository. The strange thing I observe now is that on my notebook I do have the texts, but on my deskopt as well as on the build created via AzureDevOps I don't - all three are on the same commit. Maybe I'm missing something here..

Comment: I actually can reproduce the issue on my notebook as well. every time when I add a new string it won't show up until "something" happens. Not sure what that something is.. If you have a moment, would be interessting if you could reproduce it when you checkout or download the repo.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I found out that the issue is several language files (see my edit 2)

Comment: Sorry, a minimal repro would be better. What languages are you trying to localize into? Does it matter which language(s) are missing, or if ANY are missing does it fail?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the AppResource.Designer.cs and change the methodenames down below. In my case they didn't update to the new names of the strings, so I couldn't pick them.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your Code Generated by the "ResXFileCodeGenerator" have not updated the Code for your newly added strings.

To refresh the code that was auto generated, try Right Click on the Resx -> Run Custom Tool, Rebuild the Application and Run.

Before all the steps , make sure that the resx is having the right autogenerated .cs file mapped in the .proj file and the "ResXFileCodeGenerator" is selected in the "Custom Tool" in the properties.

Comment: The ResXFileCodeGenerator is set and also I tried Run Custom Tool, rebuild, delete bin and obj.. Also I built it on the build server and the same there.

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation I figured out that the issue is that there was no default language set for the .net library. After I added this to the .csproj resolving worked again:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Not that I had the default language set in the package reference, but as it seems that is not / no longer enough in that case.